# Error Deploy72002 when using hosted agent but works when using local agent

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, sqlproj

I am new to VSTS and I am trying to get a msbuild task to publish a SQL Server project using a publish profile.

The build task works if I use a local agent but fails when I try with a Microsoft-hosted agent (Hosted VS2017), error below.

Is there something I should add to the firewall rules for the database server?

I am using `Integrated Security=False` and the server is Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit) ver. 13.0.4001.0.

msbuild arguments: `/t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=Archive.publish.xml`

> error: D:\a\1\s\TestSolutions\Application\Archive\bin\Debug\Archive.publish.sql(0,0): Error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to target server '{theserver}'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps admins have only allowed connections to port 1433 from certain machines.

Answer (score 0):

The hosted agent doesn't have access to your network. It cannot deploy to a server that isn't accessible over the internet.

Comment: Yes. It would appear that there are IP filters to the database. The IP address of the hosted agent changes for each invocation so we cannot add firewall rules for those. We'll make do with local agents then. Thank you.